# RxJS: Are there any disadvantages of Single Observables over Multiple Separate Observables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

RxJS: On a server in Node.js in the app I'm currently working on I'm trying to determine which would be better: a single stream that handles all outgoing emissions from observables (which get further emitted by socket connections), or dividing my observables into categories.  Are there any disadvantages of one way over the other?  Let me illustrate what I am trying to ask...

For example: if you were to make a chat application would you set up a single stream and have subscriptions filtered out by chat room such as:

```
handleEverythingObservable // STREAM OF ALL ROOMS
  .filter(obj => obj.chatRoom === joinedChatRoom)
  .subscribe(emitToConnectedSocket);
```

Or would you have an object that divides the streams into categories such as rooms and have multiple separate streams, like:

```
objectOfObservables = {
  room1: room1Observable, // STREAM OF A SINGLE ROOM
  room2: room2Observable // STREAM OF A SINGLE ROOM
};

objectOfObservables.room1.subscribe(emitToConnectedSocket);
// NO FILTERING NECESSARY
```

Are there any design principles that would lead you to choose one way over the other, or would you even do something totally different?  Would there be any disadvantages to choose one of these patterns?  If a single observable had to handle every single object, it seems that there might be a chance for blocking. 
 I'm thinking that if I divide up the streams, I could terminate them if they were empty, and reopen them when a subscriber was looking for a particular room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case i would go for centralized observable.

1. on room join observable are very similar streams, besides the name of the room, not much point to split them up and increase complexity
2. In case of blocking, either approach the observable you created are supposed to support combine, slicing, delay etc in order to be reused. Whether it will create blocking are normally depends on those small observable segments u will be making e.g forget to retry observable when it fail sliently, or poor error handling etc. You always debug with .do() operator
3. With approach on you can always create a seperate room stream if you need to

   let roomA$=handleEverythingObservable.filter(obj => obj.chatRoom ===joinedChatRoom).filter(obj=>obj.name==='roomA')
4. In my opinion splitting is easier than combining (likely to run into async/sync issue if not handled well in some case)  and allow better flexibility

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like the way that you put it.  I will structure it in a single stream to keep simplicity.